# What Facebook Graph API event handles the "Get Started" button?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

I'm working on a bot using the Facebook Graph API version 2.6. I need to have the bot message the user when they click the "Get Started" button in Messenger. What messaging API event handles this? I've tried `optin` with no success. I'm also unable to find a list of these events anywhere except in code for other bots. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can define the payload and update the thread settings using the API metioned in the following url:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/messenger-profile/get-started-button

Comment: Thanks. I subscribed to messaging_postbacks in the app settings, but my app isn't receiving any data when the get started button is pressed. I checked that the verify token was set - what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: have you enabled weehooks for your app.

Comment: Yes - it works for normal messaging through facebook.com which doesn't have a Get Started button

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you manage to handle the 'get_started' button?